# Bootstrap span different columns based on different orienations

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a beginner in using bootstrap 3. But I have a div which should span 6 columns on Desktop, Mobile and Tablet-Landscape  and span 8 columns on Tablet-Portrait.

I am tyring to create my own css classes, since I am not aware of another way.

```
<div class="my-col-xs-ld-6 td-col-xs-ld-offset-3 td-col-sm-pr-8 td-col-sm-pr-offset-3">
     Content here
</div>
```

Css

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .td-col-xs-ld-6 {
  }
}

@media screen and  (orientation:landscape) {
  .td-col-xs-ld-offset-3 {
  }
}
```

I understand that I have two create different orientation for each class. But I am stuck here, didn't know how I can implement this.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you compile the CSS from SASS or LESS?

Answer (score 1):

This can help you:

the grid system limits: 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options

And the usual size of each of the most used devices with their sizes:
https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Now, compare the sizes of each one and set the columns according to your need, for example, a device (tablet) in portrait can achieve 1024px, so you can use col-md-2 or col-lg-2 (this will create 6 same sized columns inside one row) and for a larger screen, such as more than 1024px, you use col-xl-2 (it will create 6 columns in one row).

Always remember that bootstrap grid system uses a total of 12 columns inside one row, so you can split those 12 in many ways, but it need to sum always 12 in the end. for example:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

**EDIT**
So, if i understood correct, you want to create your own CSS style for columns like bootstrap have, not use bootstrap.
So, this is the basic bootstrap style for all kinds of columns, you can use this base:

```
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
```

now, for each size you want, you will need to define widths, preferable in %, to be more responsive. (Example: for 4 columns, divide 100%, the total width, in 4, so 25%, or something similar [remember that if you have margin, you need to subtract from the width])

Use media queries for at least 4 device sizes, example:  less than 576px, less than 768px, less than 992px ,and bigger than 992px...

Comment: it uses the same logic, always 12 columns. but, here it is:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php

Comment: didn't understand. can you provide some sample code

Comment: Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mskz2r6p/
resize the window to see the effect there, try to change the cols to see the effect of each one

Comment: how is that related to my question, I need different spanning based on orientation. I see you are using the traditional bootstrap columns.

Comment: Sorry, so you want to create CSS styles to manipulate your own columns, thats it?
For that, I think you will need media queries, as you already have, and define widths with percentage for the sizes you want to create for each type of column.